# azure ml & Pytorch: sample conda-dependencies.yml and docker?

Tags: docker, pytorch, azure-machine-learning-service

Could you please point me to the documentation sample showcasing how to put together pytorch dependencies for training on AzureML?
Few related questions to the scenario of running pytorch training workloads on AzureML:

- How can I set cuda version to 10.1?
- Could you please point to sample demonstrating how to use “official” pytorch docker https://hub.docker.com/r/pytorch/pytorch  (which should have all cuda stuff https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/docker/pytorch/Dockerfile)?.
- I’ve found [distributed-pytorch-with-horovod.ym](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/ml-frameworks/pytorch/training/distributed-pytorch-with-horovod/distributed-pytorch-with-horovod.yml)l in the docs but it does not mention any pytorch dependencies  -- am I looking in the right place?

Answer (score 1):

Install [Pytorch](https://pytorch.org/) with CUDA Version 10.1 with the following command on windows
pip3 install torch===1.3.1 torchvision===0.4.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.htm.

[image]

From .yml file:
https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/ml-frameworks/pytorch/deployment/train-hyperparameter-tune-deploy-with-pytorch/train-hyperparameter-tune-deploy-with-pytorch.yml
[image]

Please follow the below documents for pytorch on Azure.

https://notebooks.azure.com/pytorch

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/pytorch-on-azure-full-support-for-pytorch-1-2/